# ¿Como hacer busquedas en varias hojas Excel y poner resultado en otra?

Tags: python, pandas

Un saludo a todos, os voy a exponer un problema que tengo a ver si me podeis ayudar para hacerlo con python y pandas.

Imaginad que tenemos una hoja excel: nombre.xlsx y otra hoja con frases: frases.xlsx

La hoja nombre tiene como indica nombres en una columna :

Juan
Pedro
MAria
..... etc

La hoja frases tiene frases de este estilo en una columna:

Juan cuenta mentiras
Juan cuenta cuentos
Juan cuenta chistes
Alberto cuenta mentiras
Alberto cuenta cuentos
Alberto cuenta chistes
.....etc

Lo que quiero hacer es que con me digais como se puede hacer que vaya nombre a nombre de la hoja nombres y busque para ese nombre las frases con mentira y chiste y me lo ponga en otra hoja aparte de esta manera:

Columna 1-----------Columna 2--------------------Columna 3
Juan---------------Juan cuenta mentiras---------Juan cuenta chistes

No se si me he explicado suficientente bien.
Quedo a la espera de vuestras respuestas.
Gracias.

Comment: **¿Qué has intentado?** Lee [ask].

Comment: Puedes buscar las palabras en el dataframe usando `str.contains()`. Te invito a leer la documentación de [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)